# Why was this sailor painting a Swastika on a US Destroyer?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, greyhound

In the WWII movie [*Greyhound* (2020)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6048922/), at about 25:00 we can see a sailor painting a [Swastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika) symbol on the ship. This happens right after they have sunk a Nazi U-Boat.

[image]

Why was this sailor painting a Swastika on the ship? Was it a count of U-Boat kills? Is it realistically depicted in the movie?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Those are [victory or kill marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_marking). It was very common for tanks, planes and ships to mark their kills on both the Allied and Axis sides during the war.

[image: kill board on a naval vessel with various markings for military, supply and merchant ships]

[Image source](https://subsim.com/radioroom/showthread.php?t=211324)

The "Rising Sun" flags indicate the sinking of a military naval combatant vessel, the red dot flags are supply ships, and the pennants indicate merchant vessels. The half flags indicate an assist - some other ship claimed the kill.

At some point since the War, it's become more common to use generic symbols rather than national flags, but the practice still continues.

Comment: I remember in "Baa Baa Black Sheep" (I think the movie, but it could have been the TV show) one of the pilots kept crashing his own plane, and they painted small us flags on his new plane. One character remarked that if he crashed that plane, he'd become a Japanese Ace. :)

Comment: The train kill mark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Barb_(SS-220)#/media/File:USS_Barb_crew_1945_i03570.jpg

Comment: @Joshua: That's a badass flag. That crew must be named "Ambassadors of Death".

Comment: Wait, train kill from a warship? That sounds like a story worth listening to

Comment: @slebetman From a _submarine_. Apparently she landed a shore party that went in and set explosives.

Comment: @slebetman: [There you go.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6Ed7EQiLXU&ab_channel=SmithsonianChannel). Sad to know that upon decommissioning it was sold for scrap. Such a shame !